# Deserialization error in XML document(1,1)

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I have an XML file that I deserialize, the funny part is the XML file is the was serialized
using the following code:

```
enter code here
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CommonMessage));
var writer = new StreamWriter("OutPut.txt");
serializer.Serialize(writer, commonMessage);
writer.Close();
```

And i m trying to deserialized it again to check if the output match the input. 
anyhow here is my code to deserialize:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CommonMessage));
var reader = new StringReader(InputFileName);
CommonMessage commonMessage = (CommonMessage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: Have you serialized it using one encoding and now are trying to deserialize with another encoding?

Comment: no here is what i use the serialized  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CommonMessage));
                var writer = new StreamWriter("OutPut.txt");
                serializer.Serialize(writer, commonMessage);
                writer.Close();

Comment: @jprbest - if you want to add information, please _edit_ the question and add the detail there instead of a comment.

Comment: ok sorry i ll do it write now

Comment: from my experience, error at (1,1) most often results from me opening a document with a notepad and accidentally putting a space or a new line at the top.

Comment: There should be better details in the InnerException.  Can you share those details?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Replace StringReader with StreamReader and it will work fine. StringReader reads value from the string (which is file name in your case).

Comment: this was the problem because the stream reader/writer encode/decode using UTF 8 while string reader/writer encode/decode usng UTF 16

Comment: So many thanks for this! This is an error so subtle, for sure you can search it for long time without finding the problem...

Comment: Worked well for me. Had to ignore DtDProcessing as well.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same error message but different error source. In case someone has the same problem like me. I chopped off the very first `char` of my xml string by splitting strings. And the xml string got corrupted:

```
"?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> ..." // my error
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?> ..." // correct
```

(1,1) means basically *first char of the first line is incorrect* and the string can't be deserialized.

Answer (score 1):

include in your CommonMessage class the XmlRoot element tag with your xmlroot   eg:[XmlRoot("UIIVerificationResponse")]

Answer (score 0):

You should disable the order mark in the StreamWriter constructor like this:

UTF8Encoding(false)

Full sample:

```
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false)))
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize, ns);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
        }
```