# There is an error in XML document (1, 1). while deserializing

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I am using **Silverlight** for my serializing and deserializing.

I ahve succesfully done serializing by obtaining objects from the class and the xml which i obtained on serializing , the **same xml** i am trying to deserialize.

My code to do so is:

```
namespace SliderLastTry
{
    public class ControlClass
    {
        public void Main()
        {

            Parameters pc = new Parameters()
              {
                  Parameter = { new Parameter { Name = "Name1", Label = "Label1", Unit = "Uint1", Component = { new Component { Type = "Type1", Attributes = { new Attributes { Type = "Combo", Displayed = "42", Selected = "02", Items = { "10", "11", "12", "13", "14" } } } } } }, { new Parameter { Name = "Name2", Label = "Label2", Unit = "Uint2", Component = { new Component { Type = "Type2", Attributes = { new Attributes { Type = "Slider", Displayed = "52", Selected = "05", Items = { "20", "21", "22", "23", "24" } } } } } } } }
               ,
                  Separator = { new Separator { Separators = "AutoSkew1" } }
              };
            String xml = pc.ToXml(); //This function serializes and returns xml.
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parameters));
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));
            Parameters parameter = (Parameters)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

**This line in this code gives me exception:**

```
Parameters parameter = (Parameters)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

Thsi is code for serializing (I mean the class where MyXML is defined):

```
namespace SliderLastTry
{
    public static class Xml
    {
        public static string ToXml(this object objectToSerialize)
        {
             var memory = new MemoryStream();
             var serial = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
             serial.Serialize(memory, objectToSerialize);  
            var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            return utf8.GetString(memory.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memory.Length);  
        }
    }
}
```

And the warning obtained is:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 1).
```

Please see the exception in details:

Inner Exception:

```
 {System.Xml.XmlException: Invalid data at root level. Line 1, position 1. 
        to System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (Exception e) 
        to System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (String res, String arg) 
        System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace to () 
        System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent to () 
        System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read to () 
        System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent to () 
        Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderParameters.Read7_parameters to ()}
```

At stack Trace:

```
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize (XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, Object events)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize (XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize (XmlReader xmlReader)
SliderLastTry.ControlClass.Main to ()
ctor to SliderLastTry.MainPage .. ()
at SliderLastTry.App.Application_Startup (Object sender, e StartupEventArgs)
at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler (UInt32 indexType, handlerDelegate Delegate, Object sender, Object args)
at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent (unmanagedObj IntPtr, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, argsTypeIndex Int32, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

Comment: Does this link help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726208/deserialization-error-in-xml-document1-1

Comment: Does the error have an `InnerException`?

Comment: @DavidG - likely not, 99% it is BOM issue (first character of the string is BOM mark, not `<` as required). It is just wrong to convert stream to string the way shown in the post (likely OP knows it too, so comment).

Comment: User, I can't read tiny french, please update your question with the text from this error.. (Preferably translated)

Comment: @Sayse Ok met me update.

Comment: @DavidG when itried to replace stringreader to StreamReader i got exception: {System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path corresponding that line.

Comment: I've tried to reconstruct the error you are getting but I've got: `System.NullReferenceException` on line: `Parameter = { new Parameter { Name = "Name1", Label = "Label1", Unit = "Uint1", ... }`

Comment: @Sayse please see th edit for exception details

Comment: @rosko I have added all the classes i am using ..Please see th eedited code.

Comment: I don't have time right now to fully look into it but I can guarrantee it isn't to do with the first character in the xml, its either the root element it is expecting is different to the one given or something similar to that. Its also possible that the  xmlreader is set up incorrectly..  Again there might be an innerexception in the inner exception

Comment: @user234839 In your encoding, if you replace the `UTF8` class with `Unicode`, does that help?

Comment: @DavidG It is successfully serialized i can see the xml obtained. Still is it possible that i may have problem in deserializin due to this.

Comment: @Sayse I have updated all classes. I guess it is done properly because it would have created problem while serializinf if it was so.

Comment: @user234839 Exactly, I think the StringReader uses unicode which is causing your problem. Try encoding in unicode and let us know!

Comment: I've copy-pasted your code into VS and it's 100% working for me... it's serializing your xmlstring into xml and then deserialize. I can get any value from `parameter` and print it to the console so I think that now I don't know what is your problem.

Comment: can you see all the attributes and names by  the object obtained on debugging ?

Comment: @DavidG could you please suggest me good link to implement that or could you please write piece of code for reference ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afterall i found soluton for it.
Reaplacing this:

```
var memory = new MemoryStream();
             var serial = new XmlSerializer(objectToSerialize.GetType());
             serial.Serialize(memory, objectToSerialize);  
            var utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
            return utf8.GetString(memory.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memory.Length);
```

with

```
var writer = new StringWriter();
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer((objectToSerialize.GetType()));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, objectToSerialize);
            string xml = writer.ToString();
            return xml;
```

worked because `StringReader` is in compatible with `utf8`.