# Why do I get this error at XML Deserialization function?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have created two functions, XML serialize and deserialize.
The problem is that I get an error on derserialization.
Below you may find the functions:

```
public string Serialize(Object o)
{
    using (var writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        new XmlSerializer(o.GetType()).Serialize(writer, o);
        return writer.ToString();
    }
}

public PathDetailsMessage Deserialize(string xml)
{
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
         XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PathDetailsMessage));
         return (PathDetailsMessage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

And the calls:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PathDetailsBLL train = new PathDetailsBLL();
    PathDetailsMessage pdm = train.GetDetails();
    string xml = train.Serialize(pdm);
    PathDetailsBLL dsa = new PathDetailsBLL();
    PathDetailsMessage fds = new PathDetailsMessage();
    fds = dsa.Deserialize(pdm.ToString());
    Console.Write(fds);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

On the line `return (PathDetailsMessage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);` I get the following error:

> **System.InvalidOperationException**: 'There is an error in XML document (1, 1).'

> XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialization error in XML document(1,1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726208/deserialization-error-in-xml-document1-1)

Comment: You may have a namespace issue if the tag on first row has a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 fds = dsa.Deserialize(pdm.ToString());
```

You want to deserialize xml variable but using pdm.ToString() instead.
Try

```
 fds = dsa.Deserialize(xml);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was rushing and it seems that I used the wrong variable. This helped me to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're serializing the object returned by `train.GetDetails()` into an XML string, `xml`, but you're trying to deserialize the string (not necessarily an XML string) returned by `pdm.ToString()`. Did you, instead, intend to call `dsa.Deserialize(xml)`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This solved my issue.